# Btc in my hard drive

Tags: bitcoin-core

I really need some help.

So as you know, BTC is out there, and I recall at the beginning of 2015 when it was really not a big deal, I decided to get learn more about btc and somehow I downloaded a type of software in my laptop that allowed me mine BTC now, my laptop ran for days and really I thought it was not a good idea  i decided to cancel the process, but somehow it looks like I mined some btc, now my laptop got really full on space  so i took it to the apple store and they figured out what happened,this happened at the beginning of this year 2017, I had an external hard drive and i put all those codes, blocks, pages however they may be call into the folder and they genius guy told me that i may havce some good money there bc it was a lot.

now, with that story put out there, my question is; how can i transfer those things from my external hard drive to a physical btc wallet? so i can somehow enjoy it.

any advice will highly appreciated it.

Comment: mining with a Laptop, even with the graphics card, shouldn't provide you with a fortune. But if you want to dive deeper, maybe check for a file called wallet.dat. Assuming you had bitcoin qt (core software) installed. You can search for it in finder. Or you press left ALT key, and chose in finder "goto" menu -> Library. There is "Application Support", and maybe a bitcoin folder. Check the forum here for the tag "wallet", and search for OS X. Or the tag "wallet-recovery". There are many posts. And let us know, how it goes :-) Maybe tag your post also with "wallet-recovery".

Answer (score 1):

Nope. PC mining became unprofitable in ~2014 so you may not have mined bitcoins.

What you probably did was downloading Bitcoin Core and synchronising it (downloading and storing all the Bitcoin transactions)

Sorry, but you probably haven't earned bitcoins.

Answer (score 0):

(1) mount and symlink that external drive's `.bitcoin` folder to `$HOME/.bitcoin`.

(2) run `bitcoind`. get your balance with `bitcoin-cli getbalance`. if it's anything above 0.00000000 *then* come back for advice.